# What is and how to control Memory Storage in Executors tab in web UI?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.5.2

I use Spark 1.5.2 for a Spark Streaming application.

What is this **Storage Memory** in Executors tab in web UI? How was this to reach 530 MB? How to change that value?

[image]

Comment: How do you submit your streaming application? What are the memory settings?

Answer (score 16):

**CAUTION**: You use the very, very old and currently unsupported Spark 1.5.2 (which I noticed after I had posted the answer) and my answer is about Spark 1.6+.

---

The tooltip of Storage Memory *may* say it all:

> Memory used / total available memory for storage of data like RDD partitions cached in memory.

[image: Storage Memory in Executors tab in web UI]

It is part of **Unified Memory Management** feature that was introduced in [SPARK-10000: Consolidate storage and execution memory management](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10000) that (quoting verbatim):

> Memory management in Spark is currently broken down into two disjoint regions: one for execution and one for storage. The sizes of these regions are statically configured and fixed for the duration of the application.
>
> There are several limitations to this approach. It requires user expertise to avoid unnecessary spilling, and there are no sensible defaults that will work for all workloads. As a Spark user, I want Spark to manage the memory more intelligently so I do not need to worry about how to statically partition the execution (shuffle) memory fraction and cache memory fraction. More importantly, applications that do not use caching use only a small fraction of the heap space, resulting in suboptimal performance.
>
> Instead, we should unify these two regions and let one borrow from another if possible.

### Spark Properties

You can control the storage memory using `spark.driver.memory` or `spark.executor.memory` Spark properties that set up the entire memory space for a Spark application (the driver and executors) with the split between regions controlled by `spark.memory.fraction` and `spark.memory.storageFraction`.

---

You should consider watching the slides [Memory Management in Apache Spark](http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/memory-management-in-apache-spark) by the author Andrew Or and the video [Deep Dive: Apache Spark Memory Management](https://youtu.be/dPHrykZL8Cg) by the author himself (again).

---

You may want to read how the Storage Memory values (in web UI and internally) are calculated in [How does web UI calculate Storage Memory (in Executors tab)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43801062/1305344)

Comment: we are using a spark application which uses spark 1.5.1. Our application is not at all using storage memory. Is there any way we can reduce Storage memory in 1.51.?

Comment: Don't remember how it was in 1.5.1 and am truly shocked it's still in use. Please upgrade to 2.3.2 at your earliest convenience.

Comment: Isn't the tooltip description is slightly incorrect? It should be 'Memory used / total available memory for storage or RDD And internal Execution like shuffle, sort'

Comment: @nir Perhaps. Please report it to Spark's JIRA to bring it to the attention of Spark devs.

Comment: @nir Did you ever verify if what you said is actually the correct description?

Comment: @lightbox142 I have not. I've been off the data projects for while. I hope spark community have fixed it if needed.