# How does web UI calculate Storage Memory (in Executors tab)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to understand how Spark 2.1.0 allocates memory on nodes.

Suppose I'm starting a local PySpark REPL assigning it 2GB of memory:

```
$ pyspark --conf spark.driver.memory=2g
```

Spark UI tells that there are **956.6 MB** allocated for storage memory:

[image]

I don't understand how to get to that number, this is my thinking process:

1. Driver heap size is set to `2048 MB`,
2. According to [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management): `(2048 MB - 300 MB) * 0.6 = 1048.8 MB` are used for both execution and storage regions (*unified*),
3. Additionally `1048.8 MB * 0.5 = 524.4 MB` within unified region should be reserved as *immune storage region*

**So, how was the value 956.6 MB in Spark actually calculated?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You seem to be using `local` mode (with one driver that also acts as the only executor), but it should also be applicable to other clustered modes.

Enable the INFO logging level for `BlockManagerMasterEndpoint` to know how much memory Spark sees the property you set on the command line (as `spark.driver.memory`).

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint=INFO
```

When you start `spark-shell --conf spark.driver.memory=2g` you'll see the following:

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --conf spark.driver.memory=2g
...
17/05/07 15:20:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.8:57177 with 912.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.8, 57177, None)
```

As you can see the available memory is **912.3** which is calculated as follows (see [UnifiedMemoryManager.getMaxMemory](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/memory/UnifiedMemoryManager.scala#L210-L233)):

```scala
// local mode with --conf spark.driver.memory=2g
scala> sc.getConf.getSizeAsBytes("spark.driver.memory")
res0: Long = 2147483648

scala> val systemMemory = Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory

// fixed amount of memory for non-storage, non-execution purposes
val reservedMemory = 300 * 1024 * 1024

// minimum system memory required
val minSystemMemory = (reservedMemory * 1.5).ceil.toLong

val usableMemory = systemMemory - reservedMemory

val memoryFraction = sc.getConf.getDouble("spark.memory.fraction", 0.6)
scala> val maxMemory = (usableMemory * memoryFraction).toLong
maxMemory: Long = 956615884

import org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils
scala> JavaUtils.byteStringAsMb(maxMemory + "b")
res1: Long = 912
```

Let's review how web UI calculates the memory (which is different from what's above and is supposed to just display the value!). That's the surprising part.

How the Storage Memory is displayed in web UI is controlled by the custom JavaScript function `formatBytes` in [utils.js](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/org/apache/spark/ui/static/utils.js#L40-L48) that (mapped to Scala) looks as follows:

```
def formatBytes(bytes: Double) = {
  val k = 1000
  val i = math.floor(math.log(bytes) / math.log(k))
  val maxMemoryWebUI = bytes / math.pow(k, i)
  f"$maxMemoryWebUI%1.1f"
}
scala> println(formatBytes(maxMemory))
956.6
```

**956.6**! That's exactly what web UI shows and is quite different from what Spark's `UnifiedMemoryManager` considers the available memory. *Quite surprising, isn't it?*

---

I think it's a bug and filled it as [SPARK-20691](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20691).

Comment: Thanks for the very descriptive and exhaustive answer. The fragment causing the misunderstanding was `reservedMemory * 1.5` which should be documented somewhere (docs states that 300 MB are reserved, while in reality it's 450 MB).

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Just a comment to yours: `reservedMemory` is 300MB, but it's minimum memory that's required for a Spark app, isn't it?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski so if I want to reduce storagememory what exact parametr I should put to configuration?

Comment: @jk1 I think it'd be `--executor-memory` since a StorageManager lives there. Could you please ask a separate question so it won't falls through the cracks? Thanks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski : You should add this answer to Spark Documentation. (reservedMemory * 1.5) this is written nowhere and it makes the entire calculation haywire and then you think your entire knowledge is wrong

Comment: @ETL_Devs What a good idea! But then (after giving it a serious thought) I'm concerned I'd be left with no clients who'd pay for this precious knowledge 

Comment: the `Storage Memory`  example  `20G/1G`  ,  what is the 20G mean?  It is the total usage since app start?  thanks a lot

Comment: @roamer It's all ever to be used.

Comment: ```Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory``` is equal to 2147483648, right? If so, then.. well, I do not know scala but, is the code given right? It should compute to 1048.8 that OP has in the question not 912 as you are getting. You have computed ```minSystemMemory``` but, not used it anywhere. In computing ```usableMemory``` If you use ```minSystemMemory```(450) instead of ```reservedMemory```(300) that you have used, you should get 958.8, not 912 or 956.6